# “Index exceeds the number of array elements” for piecewise function

Tags: matlab, process, piecewise

I am trying to create piecewise functions V(t), D(t).
I try to find the piecewise, then I use the piecewise of t to construct functions and plot them.
But it shows "Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 51".
How can I fix it?
I put my code below and I really hope someone can answer it. Thaks!

```
z=zeros(1,50);
p_i=zeros(1);
p=0.023;
for i=1:50
z(i)=rand;
if z(i)>p
   p_i(end+1)=i+z(i);
end
end
n=numel(p_i);


V=zeros(1,n);
 w=zeros(1,n);
D=zeros(1,n);
V_op=zeros(1,n);
%get the number of pi
sigma_w0=0.2;
Q=5;
P=2;
Q_op=4;
for i=1:n
if i>1
    w(i)=w(i-1)+normrnd(0,sigma_w0);
    V(i)=Q*w(i);
    D(i)=P*w(i);
    V_op(i)=Q_op*w(i);

else
   w(1)=2;
   V(i)=Q*w(i);
   D(i)=P*w(i);
   V_op(i)=Q_op*w(i);
end
end



t=0:0.0002:50;
V_p=zeros(size(t));
D_p=zeros(size(t));
V_opp=zeros(size(t));
for m=1:length(t)
        t(m)>=p_i(i)& t(m)<p_i(i+1)
        V_p(m)=V(i);
        D_p(m)=D(i);
        V_opp(m)=V_op(i);

end
```

Comment: What is the value of `i` in your loop over `m`? Hint: it was last set in your earlier loop `for i=1:n`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you run your code you'll see it is functional before the last *for* loop since it is evaluating that in the 1 to 50 range (m=1:length(t)) but your line is printing 51 values so you need to check only the next part and reorganize the idea:

```
t(m)>=p_i(i)& t(m)<p_i(i+1)
```

If you print the first part (`t(m)>=p_i(i)`) it is okay, but check the other part and you'll notice the error. Maybe you can print all your results moving your increment value (+1) and prevent it from exceeding 1 to 51.